# I am listing contents of file using uisng rest api and gradle...but after getting the credentials i am getting error in eclipse

Tags: java

```
2016-03-21 15:33:36.224:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:35313
    Please open the following address in your browser:
    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=254623622510-smaa7caiaap9gavn95lo37ovavn9vvlc.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:35313/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
    Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
    2016-03-21 15:33:49.693:INFO::Stopped SocketConnector@localhost:35313
    Credentials saved to /home/vijay/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.(Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser;Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/GoogleClientRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
        at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.(Drive.java:135)
        at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Builder.build(Drive.java:8669)
        at org.gradle.DriveQuickstart.getDriveService(DriveQuickstart.java:100)
        at org.gradle.DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:105)
```

I get the above error

Comment: Looks like  incompatible jar files

Comment: i am importing google-api-client-1.21.0.jar in my code also tried others jars but its not working..can u help us??

Comment: and which Version of google-api-services-drive

Comment: we are using version2....google-api-services-drive-v2-rev93-1.13.2-beta.jar

Comment: try:     'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
 and ''com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev6-1.20.0'